# Do "he hit my eye" and "he hit me in the eye" have a nuance?

Tags: meaning

My school teacher said "he hit my eye" and "he hit me in the eye" have a subtle difference in meaning, is it true? She said the former talks about the eye and the latter talks about me with a specific target.

Comment: "He hit my eye" is simply **wrong** in the context of ELL.  (Of course, you can construct an incredibly contrived reason to use any combination of words. It's simply wrong.)

Comment: Well, if you removed your eye from your head and put it on the table, and someone hit it, "He hit my eye" would be correct and "He hit me in the eye" would be incorrect.

Comment: *Of course, you can construct an incredibly contrived reason to use any combination of words. It's simply wrong.*  John Wu has given us the perfect example of an ***incredibly contrived reason***.  This is an ongoing endless problem on the ELL site.  Someone will ask "Do you spell horse like this horse or like this hourssie".  The correct answer is "like this: horse".  But what happens is this, people write thousand-word answers on the metaphysics of spelling, the epistemology of Meaning, the world of thoroughbred breeding, etc. The actual answer is just "horse".

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that's about right. The direct object indicates what was hit "my eye" or "me".  Adding "in the eye" indicates the target or the general area in which you were hit.

So if someone punched you, they could not hit your eye (it is too small) but they could be aiming towards your eye, or their punch could hit the middle of your face where your eyes are located.  And you'd say they punched me in the eye.  Saying "hit my eye" would be less common.

But in many situations the differences aren't enough to worry about.  If you always use "hit me in the eye" you are unlikely to be wrong.

Comment: Not if it is a medical thing.  If a board bounces up, it could hit the orbit of your eye and not hit your eye per se.

Comment: The bones around your eye might protect it from being hit by a slap, but not from a punch.  Horizontal knuckles easily fit between your cheek and brow.  Vertically my fist has enough of of a curve the my middle knuckles touch my eyelid with the outer two resting on the bones above/below.

Comment: This just isn't right. "he hit my eye" sounds, precisely, like a non-fluent, English-second-language speaker.  It is *literally* the sort of phrase you'd use to parody, make fun of, someone speaks broken English.   "He hit my eye" is simply wrong. (It would only be used in extremely unusual circumstances - ***which is true of any combination of words***.)

Comment: (IMO, of course)

Answer (score 4):

The teacher is right but usually **a thing** is more likely to "hit your eye", rather than a person.

*When I pulled the stick out of the mud, **it hit my eye** or **hit me in the eye**.

*The little boy was playing with a rubber band that snapped back and **hit his eye** or **hit him in the eye**".

"hit somone in the eye" could *potentially* be more damaging than "hit someone's eye". In medical lingo, "hit an eye" could refer to the **orbit** of the eye. basically the upper and lower bony part of the eye. Whereas, hit "in the eye" would be more serious.

This is **similar** to:

The wind *hit my face* as I walked out the door.

Versus

The wind *hit me in the face* as I walked out the door.

Comment: I feel like "hit me in the eye" could also indicate a contact made by another person, possibly indeed another person's first, might have been without ill intent (unlike an intentional "hit my eye"). A situation comes to mind from martial arts training where we were trying to strike each other on the chest, not the face, but then accidentally my eye was hit because I stupidly evaded towards the spacetime coordinates of my partner's fist.

Comment: Sometimes the object is [the moon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69O4PXzAQ5Y&t=25s)

Comment: @Sixtyfive Sure, of course.

Answer (score 0):

There are nuances.

If something made contact with only your eyelid while your eye was closed, "hit my eye" would be appropriate, because the contact made was not *in* the eye.  (Think of flying insects, debris, or similar).

"Hit me in the eye" probably fits all other cases.

English is weird.

Answer (score -2):

> "He hit me in the eye."

is the NORMAL AND CORRECT phrase.

"He hit my eye" is simply wrong.  (It would only be used in extremely unusual circumstances - which is true of any combination of words.)

There is no "nuance". The shorter one is simply incorrect.

Comment: So nobody ever says  "**The ball hit** my/your/her/ **his eye**”? Can you please find supporting evidence?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hit%20his%20eye%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2014,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en **and** https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hit+my+eye%22&lr=lang_en&sca_esv=82c0f5fcf9e8a56e&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACQVn09mg9n7ncr_bEwmsMe4MHU6ZpaMdg:1706910422007&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVvffq0I2EAxXCo_0HHc-yA-4QpwV6BAgBEBo&biw=1084&bih=630&dpr=2.5

Comment: He aimed for my nose,  but he hit my eye.

Comment: Please note: Fattie said that "He hit my eye" was wrong except in unusual circumstances. That is about right, in my view. More usual is: Some thing hit my eye.

Comment: hi @Mari-LouA. you should have read on past the 1st line :)  I jave no idea what you're meaning about ".. has ever said", and the unrelated phrase you mention. I'm answering the question on this page: To simply literally cut and paste my (whole) answer) **"He hit my eye" is simply wrong. (It would only be used in extremely unusual circumstances - which is true of any combination of words.) There is no "nuance". The shorter one is simply incorrect.**

Comment: Yet, there are already two downvotes for this answer. And I have yet to cast a vote because I was hoping for a sign of humility or flexibility; by saying "End of story" means you are not open to discussion. By saying “The shorter one is simply incorrect,” contradicts **…extremely unusual circumstances…** . And without any supporting evidence,  along with the others, this answer is based only on your opinion.

Comment: Unfortunately most of the questions on this site, let's say all of a major category of questions on this site, are 100% opinion based. When an English learner asks "What is the idiomatic way..." or "How would a native speaker say..." or "Does this sound like a native speaker ...", there *is no* "reference" or "evidence" concept. (With English the written corpus is, of course, utterly irrelevant to spoken speech.) The only possible answer is "I am a native English speaker that has worked extensively with spoken word in advertising, film and TV for thirty years and in my opinion."...

Comment: .. or for that matter just "I speak and only speak English in regions ABC and in my opinion the answer is ..."  There's nothing else.  The excellent answer by JK above has absolutely not a whit, a speck, a muon, of evidence or facts. Again, as with all answers in this category of question (which is most QA on the site).  (In incredibly rare cases there might be a scientific paper on the nature oif a certain slang in certain regions, or whatever.) So unfortunately that's that. I'm delighted to delete the superfluous phrase "End of story", thanks  :)

Comment: I basically agree with this answer but I especially agree with the Fattie's comments. Much of what is asked here is about native speaker internalization of forms. Cheers. :) A great example of this was asked in a recent question re "set up". I think I showed one example of unusual circumstance in my answer.

Comment: And perhaps more important - today is 2.4.24 !  hooray !! !!!! !! !!!!